# Xubuntu power settings file

Tags: xfce, settings, xubuntu

I'd like to create a toggle for suspending/doing nothing upon closing the lid for XFCE. For that, I need to find out where is the following setting stored:

[image]

Creating the toggle script and panel indicator won't be a problem afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you need are stored in `xfce4-settings-editor`. The function you require is `lid-action-on-ac`. So, to use `xfconf-query` to set it to do nothing, you would run

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/lid-action-on-ac -t int -s 0
```

Then to set it to suspend, substitute the 0 for a 1:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/lid-action-on-ac -t int -s 1
```

The values usable with `xfconf-query` that correspond to the settings in the graphical application are:

```
lid-action-on-ac

0=nothing
1=suspend
2=hibernate
3=lock screen
```

This information was found by setting the values in the graphical settings dialog and then noting the value that appeared in `xfce4-settings-editor` under the appropriate function. You could do this for the other functions such as `power-button-action`, if you are interested in those as well.

However, you cannot use the toggle option (`-T`) here explicitly, as that only works with boolean values (true, false) and not integers. You could however just use the two `xfconf-query` commands above in a script and fashion a toggle within that script, as you said you wish to do.